# Safari service worker work incorrect with custom offline page

Tags: safari, fetch, offline, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I created a pwa version of the site with a custom offline page using the service worker. When navigating through pages, they are added to the cache, and when they are visited again, it is shown from the cache.
When you click on a link and do not connect to the Internet and this page is not cached, an offline page is displayed.

[image: offline page screen]

There are 2 options to refresh the page:

- When the Internet appears on the offline page, a link appears to
  update the page.

[image: offline page reload link]

- When the Internet appears, return to any available page (home
  page) and go to the desired page.

[image: offline page]

With the first option there is no problem. And with the second there is a problem in the safari.
The problem occurs when:

1. clicked on the link without an Internet connection and received an
   offline page
2. The next time already with the Internet connection went on the same
   link and again received an offline page, although it should show an online page

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. go to the site with the Internet turned on
2. turn off the Internet
3. go to page1.html (an offline page is displayed)
4. go back to index.html (go home link)
5. turn on the internet
6. go back to page1.html (an offline page is displayed, but page1.html
   should be displayed)
7. go to page2.html - everything works correctly, the online page loads

Who faced such a problem? It seems that the safari remembers request-response bunch and return the same result, regardless of the connection to the Internet.

```js
'use strict';

const CACHE_VERSION = 1;
const BASE_URL = location.origin + '/';
const OFFLINE_URL = '/offline.html';

const CURRENT_CACHES = {
  offline: 'offline-v' + CACHE_VERSION,
};

const URLS_TO_CACHE = [
  BASE_URL,
  OFFLINE_URL,
];


self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.offline)
      .then(cache => {
        return cache.addAll(URLS_TO_CACHE);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return self.skipWaiting()
      })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  let expectedCacheNames = Object.keys(CURRENT_CACHES).map(function (key) {
    return CURRENT_CACHES[key];
  });

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
          if (expectedCacheNames.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
    .then(() => {
      return self.clients.claim()
    })
  );
});


// fetch requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const responsePromiseFactory = () => {
    return caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.offline).then((cache) => {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(response => {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        const fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

        return fetch(fetchRequest)
          .then(response => {
            const responseToCache = response.clone();

            if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }

            cache.put(event.request, responseToCache)

            return response;
          })
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return caches.match(OFFLINE_URL)
      })
  };

  event.respondWith(responsePromiseFactory());
});
```

Tested on safari desktop v.11.1 and mobile safari ios version 11.3.1

Comment: Please post code here, not GitHub

Comment: @Dani added the code

Comment: Did you find a solution? My SW works for Safari desktop when offline but doesn't seem to work on iOS... (btw - such a pathetic browser)

Comment: @ohladkov I am facing exactly same problem in Safari only. My SW works fine for rest of the browsers. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Philippe
**Did not find** any solution. Perhaps this was fixed in the next versions of safari, did not check. In which browser version do you have this problem?

Comment: @aareeph 
**Did not find** any solution. Perhaps this was fixed in the next versions of safari, did not check. In which browser version do you have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly same scenario and by adding the following headers in my offline page Safari now serves the online page when internet connection is available.

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
</head>
```